# Show images in comments Visual Studio 2013 Pro

Tags: image, github, comments, vsix

This package says it is compatible with visual studio 2013 Pro but when I try to install the file .vsix throws an error telling me that is not compatible

https://github.com/lukesdm/image-comments

I think the .vsix file is outdated but the source code is updated, ¿What are the steps to install the extension from source project downloaded from github, or create a new .vsix file from source project that supports visual studio 2013 pro?

Answer (score 0):

The file https://github.com/lukesdm/image-comments/blob/master/ImageCommentsPackage/source.extension.vsixmanifest needs to have version 12 added in order for the visx to be installable in VS 2013 - submit a PR!